# VBA Split with limit not working as intended?

Tags: vba, split

So I am trying to run the following sub where I wish to split the string iden at the second occurrence of "_" But what I get instead is an array with the following elements "1-SWFEED-4.6.14", "10", "3_C" but what I want is an array with elements "1-SWFEED-4.6.14_10", "3_C". What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub check_split()
Dim iden As String
Dim element As Variant
iden = "1-SWFEED-4.6.14_10_3_C"

For Each element In Split(iden, "_", 3)
    MsgBox element
Next element

End Sub
```

I also tried using the limit as UBound(split(iden, "_")) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The third parameter describes the number of elements in the array that you create with Split. So when you pass 3 as a parameter split gives you three elements. "1-SWFEED-4.6.14", "10", "3_C". I don't think that there is a predefined function that lets you do what you need. Just write your own function. First locate the second underscore and then use left and right functions to get the begining and end of your iden and add them to array.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I got confused with an example on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this sub which does what I need (Thanks @Maco for the comment)

```
Sub check_split()
Dim iden As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim indexCounter As Integer
Dim concIden As String
iden = "1-SWFEED-4.6.14_10_3_C"
indexCounter = 0
For Each element In Split(iden, "_")
    If indexCounter < UBound(Split(iden, "_")) - 1 Then
        If Not indexCounter + 1 = UBound(Split(iden, "_")) - 1 Then
            concIden = concIden + element + "_"
        Else
            concIden = concIden + element
        End If
    End If
    indexCounter = indexCounter + 1
Next element
MsgBox concIden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub check_split()
    Dim iden As String, splitLocation As Integer, firstPart As String, secondPart As String

    iden = "1-SWFEED-4.6.14_10_3_C"

    splitLocation = WorksheetFunction.Find("_", iden, WorksheetFunction.Find("_", iden, 1) + 1)

    firstPart = VBA.Left$(iden, splitLocation - 1)  //prints 1-SWFEED-4.6.14_10
    secondPart = VBA.Right$(iden, Len(iden) - splitLocation) // prints 3_C
End Sub
```